# Chrome Puppeteer: Is it better to do everything via JSHandles or through page.execute()?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm writing a fairly script that does some fairly complex work using Puppeteer. However, it probably all be accomplished using `ElementHandles` in Puppeteer. So, I wanted to know what's the better options:

1. Just shove a big chunk of code into page.evaluate() and call it a day
2. Access everything via `ElementHandles` using functions like `page.$()`

I would assume that passing these element handles should probably get pretty expensive...

Answer (score 2):

Consider a situation in which you want to access the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of an element on a web page using Puppeteer.

It is over **2x faster** to handle an element inside [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) directly than it is to pass the element to the function as an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle).

Furthermore, it is even **faster** to pass the `pageFunction` **as a string** to `page.evaluate()` rather than as a function.

You can make an additional micro-optimization by using [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) inside `page.evaluate()` rather than [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

The slowest method would be to use [`elementHandle.getProperty()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname) in conjunction with [`elementHandle.jsonValue()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlejsonvalue). Using this method would require you to wait **over 4x longer** (compared to the fastest method in this experiment).

**You can see the tests performed and the results below:**

```
await page.evaluate('document.getElementById("result").textContent');           // ≈ 0.41 ms ✔
await page.evaluate('document.querySelector("#result").textContent');           // ≈ 0.42 ms
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('result').textContent);       // ≈ 0.42 ms
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#result').textContent);       // ≈ 0.44 ms
await page.evaluate(result => result.textContent, await page.$('#result'));     // ≈ 0.99 ms
await (await (await page.$('#result')).getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue(); // ≈ 1.69 ms ✘
```

All of the above tests were run **1,000,000 times**, and the average time taken for a single iteration is shown in the comments above.

Therefore, to answer your question, it appears that the least expensive method would be to handle your code within `page.evaluate()` whenever possible.